# What is the zero, empty or null value of a struct?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct

If I have a mapping of string => custom defined struct, how do I check if a value is defined in the mapping?

The docs state that "every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros".

What is the zero-value of a custom defined struct such that one can conditionally check for its existence?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks Should i delete the topic ?

Comment: No, only off-topic or unintelligible questions should be deleted. Duplicates are quite useful to keep around as there are multiple ways to phrase a question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You check that a value is defined in the mapping by checking it is not zero.

**If an explicit setting of zero has meaning for your application, you need auxiliary data (or structure) to track when a value of zero has been explicitly set.**

A lightweight approach would be to add a `bool` property to the struct (say named `initialized`), and to set it to `true` when the zero is explicitly set.  As all bools are false (0) by default, you can check against the value `true`.

Alternatively, check that each member of the struct is zero.  If a member is a `string`, cast it to [`bytes` and then check its length is zero](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/what-is-the-zero-value-for-a-string).

**For an example** see [How to test if a struct state variable is set](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11618/how-to-test-if-a-struct-state-variable-is-set)

Another data structure or mapping may be needed depending on the application.

---

Here is a [related example on using a pair to check the meaning of zero](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#when-returning-a-value-of-say-uint-type-is-it-possible-to-return-an-undefined-or-null-like-value):

```
contract C {
    uint[] counters;
    function getCounter(uint index)
        returns (uint counter, bool error) {
            if (index >= counters.length) return (0, true);
            else return (counters[index], false);
        }
    function checkCounter(uint index) {
        var (counter, error) = getCounter(index);
        if (error) { ... }
        else { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify (because this differs from the other languages that I work in), I can check for structMapping[key].initalized == false even when that key has not been defined in the mapping?

Comment: Yes, the default value for everything in the Ethereum Virtual Machine (which Solidity is based on) is zero.  (Anything uninitialized is zero, unlike other languages where values may be "garbage".)

Comment: Would it be possible to use a string instead of a bool? (saying: I have an enum for which I have only string properties) Then: with what should you compare the string struct with? (in other words: what is the default value for a string)

Comment: @lajarre Good you asked http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/what-is-the-zero-value-for-a-string

Comment: Being able to test the value of arbitrary members before knowing whether the struct is initialised also means you might not even *need* to know the answer to that question in the first place – you can just go around assigning members right away. I know, I'm already feeling the slap of the segfault on my face too, but Solidity is its own beast.

Answer (score 9):

There's really no such thing as "empty". An uninitialized index of the mapping is simply equal to the " zero" value of the proper type.

To check if a value has been assigned, just check if `balances[msg.sender]== 0`. If a user accesses the contract, but the balance should be 0, you can use a address => int256 mapping, and use -1 for 0 balances

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkArray(bytes a) returns (bool){
    if ((a) && (a.length > 0))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Give me an error: `Operator && not compatible with types bytes memory and bool` solidity 0.4.7

Answer (score 0):

For an unsigned index value of an array of struct (say Customer)- to check if the entry exists in given array of structs, you can do something like below:

```
 struct Customer {
    string userName;
    string dataHash;
    address bank;
    int256 upVotes;
}

Customer[] public customers; 

...
//assuming we have some customers added (customers.length>0)
...

function getCustomerIndex(string memory userName) internal view returns(bool, uint256) {
    for(uint i=0; i<customers.length; i++) {
        if (stringEquals(customers[i].userName, userName)){
            return (true, i);
        }
    }
    return (false, 0);
}
```

The explicit (false, 0) suggests that the customer with given username is not found in the customers struct array.

Now in my other code I can use the above function as follow:

```
// return 1 implies customer found and removed from struct Customer array
// return 0 implies no customer found in the struct Customer array
function removeCustomer(string calldata userName) external returns (uint8) {
        (bool result, uint256 index) = getCustomerIndex(userName);
        if (result){
            for (uint i=index+1; i<customers.length-1; i++){
                customers[i-1] = customers[i];
            }
            customers.length--;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```