# Checking zero value of structure

Tags: solidity

I have the following statements:

```
Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
if (!sender || sender.voted) throw;
```

I'm new to solidity, so I might not be aware of how (or if) coercion works.

As I found out in this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-is-the-zero-value-of-a-struct),

> [...] every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros [...]

Knowing that, shouldn't the `!sender` statement above return `true`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If Voter is a struct, the code `!voter[sender]` will probably result in an error. In your case, you'll want to check the `voted` or another field in the Voter struct.

For now, checking guards via `voters[msg.sender].voted == 0` is probably the most reliable approach.

As a side note, strings can be a bit tricker: `some_string == 0` will not work.  In this case I use:

```
function(string value) { 
   if (bytes(value).length == 0)
     ...don't do it...
}
```

Comment: This is the exact same question I linked in my question. The accepted answer states _"you check that a value is defined in the mapping by checking it is not zero."_. So, my question can be rephrased as: "How can I check if a struct is not zero?"

Comment: How about voters[msg.sender].voter != 0?  The main thing is you must check a field in the struct.  Not the struct itself

Comment: Yeah, I understand the concept of guard, but I was wondering if there is a better approach :)