# What is the zero value for a string?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, string

How to verify that a string, or a struct with only string properties, is initialised or not, inside of a mapping?

According to the docs, it means checking that the element of the mapping is at its 0-value, which is unclear to me when talking about strings.

```
contract C {
    mapping (address => string) m1;
    mapping (address => StringStruct) m2;

    struct StringStruct {
        string someString; // Always defined when initialising this struct
        // There could be other string properties here...
    }
    
    function amIInBothMappings() returns (bool) {
         // Check that both m1[msg.sender] and m2[msg.sender].someString are non-0
    }
}
```

In the example: what is the best way to implement `amIInBothMappings` that checks that `msg.sender` is un-initialised in both mappings m1 and m2?

Comment: It seems that string comparison is still manual: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3238/string-compare-in-solidity   . Compare the first string to the string attribute in the struct. The zero string is just '' .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way is to check for the length of a String:

```
if (bytes(m1[msg.sender]).length != 0 && bytes(m2[msg.sender].someString).length != 0)
    // do your thing
```

See [the answer I posted here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/checking-zero-value-of-structure/2504#2504)

Comment: indeed, the bytes().length trick seems to work well!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to compare the sha3 hashes of the strings

```
if (sha3(myVariable) != sha3("")) {
 // is not empty string
}
```

However, this method is probably less efficient.