# Default value of a struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, struct

Consider the following contract in Solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Registry {
    struct Name {
        string first;
        string last;
    }

    mapping(address => Name) reg;

    function newName(string first, string last) {
        address sender = msg.sender;

        if(reg[sender] != 0) {
            throw;
        }

        reg[sender].first = first;
        reg[sender].last = last;
    }
}
```

In the `if` statement above, which is incorrect, I would like to check whether the struct `Name` is defined, or is still in the default value with all fields initialized to zero. Is there a language operator to do it?

Answer (score 8):

I would go with:

```
if (reg[sender].first != "" || reg[sender].last != "") {
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no operator but you can check the length of both strings against zero:

`if (bytes(reg[sender].first).length != 0 || bytes(reg[sender].last).length != 0) { throw; }`

Note: use of ||

Related:

- [What is the zero value for a string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/what-is-the-zero-value-for-a-string)
- [What is the zero, empty or null value of a struct?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-is-the-zero-empty-or-null-value-of-a-struct?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

To update this Answer to the latest version of Solidity. 
try the following:

`require(reg[sender].first && reg[sender].last);`