# How to test if a struct state variable is set

Tags: solidity, struct

I have the following struct defined as a state variable and conditionally set at runtime.

```
Transaction private tx;
struct Transaction {
    address to;
    uint value;
    bytes data;
}
```

I would like to check if the variable was set before executing a specific portion of my code.

```
if(tx == ??????){
    //do something
}
```

What's the best way to check if the struct is set?

Edit: It is important to note that here the struct is not stored in a mapping. Similar questions on this stackexchange are asking for structs in mapping, here this is not the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Question is possibly a duplicate of this: [What is the zero, empty or null value of a struct?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-is-the-zero-empty-or-null-value-of-a-struct?rq=1)

There are a few ways.

You can check a value if you're sure it implicitly indicates a set/not set condition.

```
if(tx.to > 0) {} // the address is set
```

You can be explicit if you prefer:

```
struct Transaction {
    address to;
    uint value;
    bytes data;
    bool isValid; // set to true whenever the struct holds data
}
```

Then you can:

```
if(tx.isValid) {
  // do something
}
```

You'll want to use the explicit method in the case that 0 or empty has meaning your application; meaning you can't use 0 as an indication of valid/inValid.

Not sure it applies in this case, but elimination of doubt about this sort thing is a bonus feature if you buy into the idea of maintaining an index of valid keys to a mapped structure.

Hope it helps.

Update: Some general examples here: [Blog: Simple Storage Patterns in Solidity](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/blog-simple-storage-patterns-in-solidity)

Comment: I linked the answer to the other "abstract" question to this Q&A which is more concrete and has its benefits.

Comment: The other question you are referencing in your answer is asking for null value of a struct in a *mapping* in my case the struct is *not* placed in a mapping. Does your solution works for struct as state variable and not stored in a mapping?

Comment: Sure. The answer above isn't concerned with where the struct came from. The case where people are unsure if a struct is explicitly written to, or just a zeroed out default is often related to retrieving them from mapping, but not necessarily so.