# Mapping member isn't initialized when creating a struct

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, struct, constructor

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract TestcaseResetObject {

    MyObject ob;

    struct MyObject {
        mapping(uint8 => uint) map;
    }

    event Output(uint number);

    function makeNew() {
        ob = MyObject();
        ob.map[0] += 1;
        Output(ob.map[0]);
    }
}
```

When I run `makeNew` repeatedly in [browser-solidity](https://remix.ethereum.org), I'm expecting to get every time the event `Output(1)`. Instead, I get `Output(1)`, `Output(2)`, `Output(3)`, etc.

It seems when I create a new `MyObject`, the map isn't actually created again.

[Another question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-is-the-zero-empty-or-null-value-of-a-struct) relates that freshly initialized struct should have a "zero" value in all its members. This seems true for `uint`'s etc. but since mapping seems to "remember" its old values this seems not to be the case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Guiseppe. The code isn't "initializing" new ob, just referencing existing.

Here's a way to have many mappings that don't collide like that. Possibly will give you some ideas.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract TestcaseResetObject {

    uint public objectCount;

    struct MyObjectStruct {
        mapping(uint => uint) map;
    }

    MyObjectStruct[] myObjects;

    event LogOutput(uint number);

    function makeNewObject() public returns(uint count) {

        MyObjectStruct memory mo;
        objectCount = myObjects.push(mo);
        return objectCount;
    }

    // object numbers start at 0 when objectCount is 1
    function incCounter(uint objectNumber, uint index) public returns(uint newValue) {
        myObjects[objectNumber].map[index] += 1;
        LogOutput(myObjects[objectNumber].map[index]);
        return myObjects[objectNumber].map[index];
    }
}
```

Let's you "`makeNewObject`" to create new mappings, and "`incCounter`" to single out a specific mapping from the array, and a specific location inside the mapping to increment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Modified the code just a little bit (formatting), hand-tested in remix so it works.

Answer (score 4):

**Mapping** is a really particular type and it's different from a simple array. From the [official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mappings):

> Mappings can be seen as hashtables which are virtually initialized
>   such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose
>   byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value. The
>   similarity ends here, though: The key data is not actually stored in a
>   mapping, only its keccak256 hash used to look up the value.
>
> Because of this, mappings do not have a length or a concept of a key or value being “set”.

This means essentially that you don't really ever initialize a *full* mapping variable (in your case, using `MyObject()` you initialize the `ob` struct, not the `map` variable).

The second time you refer to `map[0]` it correctly points to the same position as before, and so you find the old value.