# How do I check If a map entry doesn't exist for a given sender?

Tags: solidity, mapping, require

I have a map such as:

```
mapping (address => bytes32) private myMap;
```

Later in the code, in a function, I want to ensure my sender already has an entry in that given map.

Can I do this?

```
require(!myMap[msg.sender], 'there is an entry in the map already!')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the zero, empty or null value of a struct?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-is-the-zero-empty-or-null-value-of-a-struct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `bytes32` value cannot be zero in your app, then:

```
require(myMap[msg.sender] != bytes32(0x0), "No data.");
```

To avoid reinventing the wheel, have a look at [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

This explainer might unpack things in a digestible way: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Also, while it is admittedly not a great starting point for learning solidity, a general-purpose and reasonably fresh utility over here: https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet

Hope it helps.